# Bootstrap - Navbar - Text between buttons in same line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm trying to render some text in Bootstrap's navbar with buttons on both sides of it.

Problem is I unable to make them retain these positions when window width becomes too small and navbar goes vertical aligned.

Html:

```
<!-- Begin NavBar -->
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><span class="navbar-btn pull-left"><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Prev</a></span></li>
    <li class="text-center"><p class="navbar-text">Navigation</p></li>
    <li><span class="navbar-btn pull-right"><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Next</a></span></li>
    <li><a href="#">Do something</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xhgae23g/

How should it be?

Answer (score 0):

CSS styling issue: Try the `UL` as `display: block;` and the `LI`s as `display: inline-block;`. When the browser gets too narrow, they will stack instead of lining up.

Comment: Not quite what I needed but I've found answer anyway. The trick was to put links inside <p class="navbar-text">Navigation</p>. Thanks.